# Update Row Order Category wise in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two table `Images` and `Category` in SQL Database. The `Images` images contains `imageorder` column which right now contains random order, so I wanted to do is re-arrange that order starting from 1 and so on but it should be category wise.

For example, Category table contains `Twowheeler` and `Fourwheeler` categories and `Images` table contains 10 rows out of 4 rows for `Twowheeler` and 6 rows for `Fourwheeler`.

SO, `imageorder` column should update like 1,2,3,4 for `Twowheeler` and 1,2,3,4,5,6 for `Fourwheeler`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this:

```
WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY categoryid ORDER BY imageOrder) rowID
    FROM Images 
)
UPDATE IMages
SET ImageOrder = DS.rowID
FROM Images I
INNER JOIN DataSoruce DS
    ON I.ImageId = DS.ImageID;
```

The idea is to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to order the images. We are using `PARTITION BY` because we want to reset the order for each `category`. Also, we need to use a [Common Table Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to `store` this data and then to use it in the `INNER JOIN` statement - we are not allowed to use `ROW_NUNMBER` function directly in `UPDATE` statement.